# Spring security group based authorization

Tags: security, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

i intend to make group based permission scheme but i am confused about the following:

i have some questions:

1. What is the best approach `User > Group > Roles > Permissions` **or** 
   `User > Roles > Permissions`
2. How to implement the security (login/remember me) in this case (need a link to good tutorial).
3. The method level security will use the annotation `@PreAutorize hasPermission(#, '')` or hasRole or what ?
4. How will i hide components (administration for non admins) in the UI depending on the permissions (UI is JSF) ?
5. If i hided components in the view what will be the importance of the method level security then ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To design a security model is not a simple task itself, and without detailed knowledge of the domain, you're trying to secure it's close to impossible. Having said that any advice you can get here will be as general your question is.

1) In most applications the `User -> Roles` is enough. In more complex ones the `User -> Roles -> Permissions` could be used, but it all depends on how you'll define the scope of each. Often fine-grained roles and assigning a couple of them to the user is just what you'll need. I'd say putting another level be adding `Groups` in the middle is a bit too much. Imagine it as a file system - flat-file systems exist and are way less complicated as it may seem. Take your time while deciding this as this is one of the most important decisions and will have many implications that are not always easy to predict.

2) The authentication and remember-me mechanisms are already implemented in Spring Security - all you need to do is choose the implementation that best suits you and configure it using the security namespace support. Do take a look at [Petclinic](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic) example app, if you haven't already.

3) If you decide on using permissions, you should **always** check for permissions. Keep the gain level you chose. Be consistent. Always.

4) Depending on the view technology you use, the [JSP taglib](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html) may come in handy (as mentioned by Ralph). There is a non-such thing for JSF - but it's relatively simple to write something similar.

5) As Ralph said, if you hide something it doesn't mean it doesn't exist any more - it still can be called by an unprivileged user.

Comment: A very good answer that should get much more upvotes than tons of "overvoted" ones.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Security 4-SNAPSHOT

**Authority Groups**

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#authority-groups

*An alternative approach is to partition the authorities into groups and assign 
groups to the user.*

Answer (score 1):

5) Even if you hide some funсtion in the GUI, a malignant user could send a faked HTTP request that invokes your function.

4) For JSP there is the [spring security tag lib](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html), maybe there is something similar for JSF

3) Depends on your implementation of Role - Permission assignment

2) Authentication and remember me is independent of using groups or not.

1) Depends on your needs. Groups make it more difficult, so I would start with User-Role-Permission and would add groups late when I really need it. -- *Spring comes with an out of the box solution to assign Users to Privileges. Adding Roles is easy. But if you start with Groups you have to implement it by your own.*

**I strongly recommend reading the Spring-Security-Docs.
Either you do it in the by spring security recommended way: "[Suggested Steps for Getting Started with Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html)" or you read the (very good) book "[Spring Security 3](http://www.springsecuritybook.com/)" (written by some of the authors of the framework).**

If you follow the tutorial you will find how to do a simple login and remember me.

To differ roles and authorities you have two choices.

- There is an integrated solution in spring 3 (you have to search for your one - I don't use it.)
- You can implement your own authorization provider that adds the authorities by the already assigned roles.

Comment: thanks for your great answer, but i really need little more details on the following points 3- i assume that method such addUser or deleteUser do a specific action so it will require only permission check, right ? 2- please give me a good link for implementing authentication and remember me 1- what is so bad with groups, and what is the advantages of it over roles, meaning why should i use it ? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jsword: I don't want to be impolite, but security is a theme which you really need to understand. So I strongly recommend to read some more about Spring Security.

Comment: you are very right, i need to read more, that's why i asked for a good tutorial, thanks a lot.

Comment: There are many tutorials out there. Some were mentioned in this thread. The new books for Spring security are out. Manning press has one that you could download and start practicing from within minutes. Use your favorite search engine - 'spring security groups authentication code' would make a useful search.