# the role and permission in spring security 3

Tags: spring-security

I am new in ss3,and I have read its reference,also I read the spring security book.

However I do not find anything about the role-permission.

For example,here is the config for form-based authentication.

```
  <http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/add/**" access="hasRole('USER_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/delete/**" access="hasRole('USER_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page='/login.jsp'/>
  </http>
```

I want to control the user operation(add/delete):

```
<intercept-url pattern="/user/add/**" access="hasRole('USER_ADMIN')"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/user/delete/**" access="hasRole('USER_ADMIN')"/>
```

I define the role of 'USER_ADMIN',but this is not enough,since I want to differ the user who have 'add' permission from user who have 'delete' permission.

Maybe I can add more roles like 'user_admin_add' and 'user_admin_delete'.

But I do not think this is a good idea since the 'add' or 'delete' are permissions,not roles.

How to make it?

Also,it seems that all the roles should be configed to the xml file,I wonder if I can add new roles and permissions dynamically(in the administrator page)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of roles as a privileges. And granulate them as much as you need. Another thing is that maybe you should make a more RESTFul implementation. But this is another thread.

For example, your "delete" could be a "DELETE" HTTP method. Then you could be:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/users/*" method="DELETE" access="ROLE_DELETE_USER" />
```

and a `curl -X DELETE -u login:password 'http://example.com/users/1'`

would delete the `user` with id `1`.

By a RESTFul, since uris are either identifiers or actions, there is no use in add roles (privileges) dinamically. Since those roles are meant to be used against a new resource that should contain the xml file.

I'm afraid you cannot do this, unless you use `**` wildcards. Which in my opinion if used uncarefully can lead to troubles.

Comment: more RESTFul implementation? can you provide more details? I am interest. :) BTW,how about add roles dynamically?

Comment: add roles dinamically? I don't understand sorry.

Comment: But in the html page,how to build the link '/user/1' to use the http delete method?

Comment: By add roles dinamically I mean that the administrator of the system can add more roles use the page. I can easily add these roles to the db,but how to make add them in the ss config xml?

Comment: @hguser You want to have dynamic roles **and** define them in the security config file ?

Comment: Iam stupid. as Udo Fholl say,there is on need for adding the role to the configuration file,just add them to DB. In fact,I want to know if I wantto modify the privileges for specified role?

Answer (score 3):

> Maybe I can add more roles like 'user_admin_add' and 'user_admin_delete'.

This is the way. Permissions are roles and generally there are people who view differentiation between them as unneeded.

I don't think there is much difference in having a role **ROLE_USER_ADDER** or a permission **PERMISSION_ADD_USERS**.

You can however use roles as a concept to group permissions if you need to. For instance you can have a role admin which can add and remove users. So the role **ROLE_ADMIN** will have **PERMISSION_ADD_USER** and **PERMISSION_REMOVE_USER**. Still spring will view both roles and permissions simply as authorities.

As for dynamic roles adding you can do it by loading the current user permission from your DB for instance. Have a look at the `UserDetailsService` of spring security. The `UserDetails` object it returns has a `getAuthorities()` method which you can populate from your DB.

```
/**
 * Returns the authorities granted to the user. Cannot return <code>null</code>.
 *
 * @return the authorities, sorted by natural key (never <code>null</code>)
 */
Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities();
```

[Here](http://www.codercorp.com/blog/spring/security-spring/writing-custom-userdetailsservice-for-spring-security.html) is a very good example of implementing your own `UserDetailsService`.

Answer (score 2):

In my personal opinion spring security has several (lets say) unfortunately chosen names. So do not pay so much attention to the Term "Role" it works perfectly if you use it for privileges.

In my applications a use a naming convention to choose between Roles ans Privileges. (roles are written upper case, privileges lower case). But pay attention the Role Voter will pay attention only the the strings that starts with "ROLE" (Default configuration, can be changed.)

See also [Spring security group based authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7712669/280244)

Answer (score 0):

You should be thinking of roles more along the lines of, well, roles, rather than permissions. If you want to differentiate between adding and removing users, you might define roles described as ROLE_SALES and ROLE_USER_ADMIN. Sales staff might well need to be able to add new users into a system.

Regarding the dynamic application of roles, you should look at the architecture of Spring Security. You'll most likely want to use, or implement, a suitable `UserDetailsService`. See the [UserDetailsService reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html#d0e1613).

If you're storing your user authorization information in a JDBC database, for example, you might want to use the [JdbcDaoImpl](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html).

There are some examples of using different authentication providers in the [namespace introduction](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-auth-providers).